Zero Subtotal Checkout and custom status
I have made a new Order Status 'Paid'. I have assigned the new status to more or less every payment method and it works everywhere.
Beside on Zero Subtotal Checkout - it keeps resulting in state:new, status:processing, even though I chose the new method as "New Order Status" in config??
